# jQuery: select all inputs with unique id (Regex/Wildcard Selectors)

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors, wildcard

I have some textboxes on a webform that have ids like this:

```
txtFinalDeadline_1
txtFinalDeadline_2
txtFinalDeadline_3
txtFinalDeadline_4
```

In my jQuery how do I find all of those in order to assign a value to them. Before I had the underscore and they were all named txtFinalDeadline I could do this and it worked.

```
$(this).find("#txtFinalDeadline").val(formatDate);
```

However, that was when they were all named the same thing. Now I have the _x after the name and I'm not sure how to go about assigning that same value as before to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if I can guarantee "in order", but this elector should work:

`$(this).find('input[id^=textFinalDeadline_]').val(formatDate);`

Even then, jQuery is optimized to handle `id`s in a special way, and may only process 1 id.

A better way would be to have these textfields use a class (perhaps `date`) so you could just use the `'.date'` selector.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways to do a regex or wildcard select:

<strike>Using jQuery selector's inline wildcards:</strike>

```
$('#textFinalDeadline_\\S*').val(formatDate);
```

**update:** *I noticed that this method is no longer working since jQuery 1.3.2.*

Using CSS3 selectors:

```
$('input[id^=textFinalDeadline_]').val(formatDate);
```

Using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) & `match()`:

```
$('input').filter(function(){
  return this.id.match(/txtFinalDeadline_*/);
}).val(formatDate);
```

At last you might want to use a [regex selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/).

```
$('input:regex(id, txtFinalDeadline_*)').val(formatDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) help you?