# CSS selector to select an id with a slash in the id name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got `<span id="/about-us">` being generated by this CMS I'm using.

I'd like to select this element with jQuery but it doesn't seem to like selecting elements with a slash in them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please note: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp :
Naming rules for ID: * Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z, * Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."), * Values are case-sensitive

Comment: Is it truly impossible to fix the CMS? This might come back and bite you in some odd way.

Comment: HTML5 allows this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Please accept answer from @AGuyNamedGerald. Much more succinct and dynamic of an answer

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you can do

```
$("#\\/about-us")
```

Comment: Thank you... I prefer your answer.

Comment: I guess you got a few lucky points here. I upvoted, assuming this would work. It doesn't, at least in my case. My slash isn't at the beginning of the id. $("#10.0.0.0\\/8") selects nothing, even though "10.0.0.0/8" is the id of a real DOM object.

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman you sure? I just tested it on `id=BVB/IBD_Required` and `$('#BVB\\/IBD_Required')` worked

Comment: @KolobCanyon That was two years ago. I've since changed jobs and don't recall the browser and jQuery versions, but I believe I had my sanity back then. I likely said that it didn't work for me because it didn't work for me. Glad to hear it works for you. It's a clever solution!

Answer (score 33):

you can do it like this

```
     $("span[id*='/about-us']")
```

where it will return the span with '/about-us' in it's id attribute.

Answer (score 15):

Use the regular way:

```
document.getElementById('id/with/slashes')
```

Comment: This is a totally valid answer, but I personally find it bad practice to have one or two vanilla javascript lines where the rest uses jQuery. To keep consistent you could `$(document.getElementById('id/with/slashes'))` but that isn't very pretty.

Comment: @KolobCanyon lol... valid point. My comment was more focused on the value that would be assigned from the statement in question. If other places in code expect jQuery objects passed to them, wrapping a getElementById in `$()` would help avoid inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery escapeSeletor to do this.

```
$("#" + $.escapeSelector("id/with/slashes"))
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, $.escapeSelector() works perfectly in my case - its just a shim for the CSS Working Group's CSS.escape() method.

Answer (score 0):

see

[Regex Selector for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)

or [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707265/jquery-select-all-inputs-with-unique-id-regex-wildcard-selectors)