# How do I select and replace the contents of a div where the table row id is a shortened url using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want to replace the contents of the `<div class="clicksAllTime">` but I cannot get it to work. The HTML below is part of a table. Each row has a different ID whch is a specific shortened url that im doing an ajax call on...

HTML:

```
<tr id="http://goo.gl/zxCR" class="shortenedUrl odd">
    <td class="center">
        <div class="clicksAllTime">
            <img src="../images/loading-gif-small.gif">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#http://goo.gl/zxCR.clicksAllTime').empty().append('<p>' + response[0].analytics.allTime.shortUrlClicks + '</p>');
```

Comment: why would you make your id a url for?  You may need an escape character.

Comment: is it the fact that its a url causing the problem ? If it is then I could edit it and strip the http:// off server side... so it would be `id="zxCR"`

Comment: try it out....its sounds like a strong possibility.

Comment: far too many special characters in your ID... bad concept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a selector that works. Am using html() to replace with text for demo so you can easily test

Working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/zKSGP/

```
 $('#http\\:\\/\\/goo\\.gl\\/zxCR .clicksAllTime').html('New Text')
```

Note spcae befor "clicksAllTime classs was missing in example. Also don't need to use empty().append(),  just use html() it replaces all inside element

Comment: thanks very much for this. Your observation of the missing space was the main problem area. I have also done some server side processing to strip the `http://goo.gl/` off to make the id simpler. And it is now working! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.clicksAllTime').html('<p>' + response[0].analytics.allTime.shortUrlClicks + '</p>');
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <tr id="http://goo.gl/zxCR" class="shortenedUrl odd">
        <td class="center">
                <div class="clicksAllTime">
                        <img src="../images/loading-gif-small.gif">
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but unless im missing something this selects every instance of `class=clicksAllTime`. I have a table with many rows each with the `class=clicksAllTime` in them

Comment: this will affect any row that has the class in it

Comment: you said the contents of <div class="clicksAllTime"> so i thought thats what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

This may work.Just try bellow code / is treated as special characters.

```
$('#http:\\//goo.gl\\/zxCR.clicksAllTime').empty().append('<p>' + response[0].analytics.allTime.shortUrlClicks + '</p>');
```

check this [CSS selector to select an id with a slash in the id name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153986/css-selector-select-id-with-slash-in-the-id-name)